# Field Extension of $\mathbb{R}\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

Can someone help me to prove $[\mathbb{R}(x):\mathbb{R}\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)]=2$? My intuition the basis is $\{x,x+\frac{1}{x}\}$ but I cannot prove. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The minimal polynomial of $x$ is $t^2-(x+1/x)t+1$.

To see that $x$ doesn’t lie in $\Bbb R(x+1/x)$, assume first that it does. $x =P(x+1/x)$ where $P$ is a polynomial.

$x= x^{-n}+a_{-n+1}x^{-n+1}+...+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+x^n$, so $x^{-n}+a_{-n+1}x^{-n+1}+...+(a_1 - 1)x+...+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+x^n = 0$. Therefore $a_1=1$ and all other $a_i =0$. But we must have $a_1=a_{-1}$ because the polynomial is symmetric in $x$ and $1/x$, which gives a contradiction.

Comment: If we evaluate your polynomial at x we got $2x^2$

Comment: @LaurencePW I‘ve edited it since

Comment: How to prove the polynomial irreducible?

Comment: If it was reducible, the minimal polynomial of $x$ would be linear, i.e. $x$ would lie in the base field, which it clearly doesn‘t.

Comment: At first I thought that too but it's still not obvious for me why $x$ not in $\mathbb{R}(X+\frac{1}{X})$

Comment: Can you explain why $x$ is not in $\mathbb{R}(x+\frac{1}{x})$?

Comment: @LaurencePW I‘ve included this in my answer now.

Comment: If $\mathbb{R}(x+\frac{1}{x})$ denotes rational function in $x+\frac{1}{x}$, does the conclusion remain same? What I mean $\mathbb{R}(x+\frac{1}{x})$ is set of all rational function while for polynomial is usually denoted by $\mathbb{R}[x+\frac{1}{x}]$

Comment: Lukas, not all the elements of $\Bbb{R}(x+1/x)$ are of the form you used. It seems to me you only covered $\Bbb{R}[x+1/x]$. To get a field you need ratios of two such beasts. It seems to me you should rule out $$xQ(x+1/x)=P(x+1/x)$$ for pairs of polynomials $(P,Q)$. Mind you, your argument extends to that :-)

Comment: @Jykri Lahtonen Yeah, I did that too but I am not confident with my argument. I look at the highest degree of both sides so deg$(Q)$=deg$(P)-1$. But I am not sure how can if $x^n$ appear, then $x^{-n}$ must too

Comment: Oh, maybe is it because the coefficient of $x^n$ and $x^{-n}$ must be same?

Comment: I got the answer, thank you for your helps @Lukas Kofler

Comment: Also for your helps @Jyrki Lahtonen